# How to find unsecured content on a webpage

Tags: https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identify “non-secure” content IE warns about](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/identify-non-secure-content-ie-warns-about)
>   [Firefox reports HTTPS page to contain non-secure elements](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13107/firefox-reports-https-page-to-contain-non-secure-elements)

My webpage is running SSL and it's showing that there is insecure content on it. In chrome I checked the console (ctrl+shift+i) and it's not showing any errors for insecure content. So, is there anything else I can use to find out whats causing chrome to flash my site as insecure?

Some background on the content that I'm running. It's a custom google map using the google maps API and it's loading a kml locally using geoxml3 AND it's not accessible outside my network.

Comment: You may also find your answer here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2043/identify-non-secure-content-ie-warns-about

Comment: According to Google, to see the list of unsecured content, you need to open the JavaScript console (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`J`), not the Resources panel.

Comment: "SslCheck" http://jitbit.com/sslcheck/ can crawl your website and find all pages with nonsecure content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle it! No no, use Fiddler. http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Then you can capture the browsers calls and it will log them and if you set it up to hook the ssl it'll show up all the ssl calls.

Then you can see what requests it is making over ssl :)

Comment: I've noticed a couple users recommend fiddler for this sort of thing in other threads. I'll check it out. TY

Answer (score 2):

Run the webpage through an online web performance testing tool like [WebPageTest](http://www.webpagetest.org/). After you start a test, it will generate a waterfall view of the elements in the page. The elements which use HTTPS will have a padlock next to them.

Alternatively, view the web page elements in the Network tab within Chrome Dev Tools. If you hover your mouse over the name of any element, it will show a tooltip with the complete URL including the HTTPS or HTTP prefix.

Comment: Thanks for letting my know about WebPageTest. I'll need to use that in the future. Unfortunately the page I'm checking isn't accessible outside my network. I should of added that to my question.

Comment: Chrome (at least as of v18.0.1025.162) shows the exact offending URL in a [console warning](http://flic.kr/p/bDkKMJ).